# Should the usual way to construct a comparative sentence be singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, comparatives, comparisons

Let's say I want to compare two animals

> A rabbit runs faster than a turtle

or

> Rabbits run faster than turtles.

Which one should I prefer?

Comment: This is a matter of style, not law. I'd prefer the briefer formulation, but I'm sure contexts exists where I'd pick the longer one.

Comment: It depends somewhat on context.  The singular form can be understood to mean the same as the plural form, but in some contexts it can also mean that a *particular* (but unspecified) rabbit consistently runs faster than a particular turtle.

Comment: [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=runs+faster+than+a+horse%2Crun+faster+than+horses&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cruns%20faster%20than%20a%20horse%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crun%20faster%20than%20horses%3B%2Cc0) seem to show that it's a fairly close-run thing.